# How to install .ipa programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

How do I install an .ipa file programmatically on iOS?
is there some framework for that?
I'm not jailbreaker, just coding some app for client, and that's what he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to install apps on the iPhone is to download them through Appstore. The .ipa files you find on the net are usually cracked apps, and obviously Apple don't want you to install those...

Comment: yes i know, but he wants it to be on some cydia repo or so, so probably it's gona be designes for jailbroken phones ... so it doesn't  matter.

Comment: Create enterprise ipa and host it in your site and use itms-services to install.